# compare file and print class

Tags: awk

I have 
file1:

```
id position 
a1 21
a1 39
a1 77
b1 88
b1 122
c1 22
```

file 2

```
id  class  position1 position2
a1  Xfact   1           40
a1  Xred    41          66
a1  xbreak  69          89
b1  Xbreak  77          133
b1  Xred    140         199
c1  Xfact   1           15
c1  Xbreak  19          35
```

I want something like this
output:

```
id  position  class
a1   21        Xfact
a1   39        Xfact
a1   77        Xbreak
b1   88        Xbreak
b1   122       Xbreak
c1   22        Xbreak
```

I need a simple awk script , which print id and position from file1, take position from file1 and compare it to file 2 positions. if position in file 1 lies in range of position 1 and 2 in file two. print corresponding class

Comment: Is this homework? It vaugely looks like it.

Answer (score 0):

One way using `awk`. It's not a simple script. The process explained in short: The key point is the variable **'all_ranges'**, when reset reads from file of ranges saving its data, and when set, stop that process and begin reading from 'id-position'
file, checks position in the data of the array and prints if matches the range. I've tried to avoid to process the file of ranges many times and do it by chunks, which made it more complex.

**EDIT** to add that I assume `id` field in both files are sorted. Otherwise this script will fail miserably and you will need another approach.

Content of `script.awk`:

```
BEGIN {
    ## Arguments:
    ## ARGV[0] = awk
    ## ARGV[1] = <first_input_argument>
    ## ARGV[2] = <second_input_argument>
    ## ARGC = 3
    f2 = ARGV[ --ARGC ];

    all_ranges = 0

    ## Read first line from file with ranges to get 'class' header.
    getline line <f2
    split( line, fields )
    class_header = fields[2];
}

## Special case for the header.
FNR == 1 {
    printf "%s\t%s\n", $0, class_header;
    next;
}

## Data.
FNR > 1 {

    while ( 1 ) {

        if ( ! all_ranges ) {

            ## Read line from file with range positions.
            ret = getline line <f2

            ## Check error.
            if ( ret == -1 ) {
                printf "%s\n", "ERROR: " ERRNO
                close( f2 );
                exit 1;
            }

            ## Check end of file.
            if ( ret == 0 ) {
                break;
            }

            ## Split line in spaces.
            num = split( line, fields )
            if ( num != 4 ) {
                printf "%s\n", "ERROR: Bad format of file " f2;
                exit 2;
            }

            range_id = fields[1];
            if ( $1 == fields[1] ) {
                ranges[ fields[3], fields[4] ] = fields[2];
                continue;
            }
            else {
                all_ranges = 1
            }
        }

        if ( range_id == $1 ) {
            delete ranges;
            ranges[ fields[3], fields[4] ] = fields[2];
            all_ranges = 0;
            continue;
        }        

        for ( range in ranges ) {
            split( range, pos, SUBSEP )
            if ( $2 >= pos[1] && $2 <= pos[2] ) {
                printf "%s\t%s\n", $0, ranges[ range ];
                break;
            }  
        }
        break;
    }
}

END {
    for ( range in ranges ) {
        split( range, pos, SUBSEP )
        if ( $2 >= pos[1] && $2 <= pos[2] ) {
            printf "%s\t%s\n", $0, ranges[ range ];
            break;
        }  
    }
}
```

Run it like:

```
awk -f script.awk file1 file2 | column -t
```

With following result:

```
id  position  class
a1  21        Xfact
a1  39        Xfact
a1  77        xbreak
b1  88        Xbreak
b1  122       Xbreak
c1  22        Xbreak
```